# Spring REST, user ressource and password

Tags: java, spring, rest

I m actually creating my first little Spring application, a Rest webservice and I m facing a problem.

In fact, I have a ressource at /users and I dont want people to get the password.

My User object contains a password field.

So what can I do to bypass this ? Can I hide the field ? Can I do something better to manage this ?

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are returning JSON from your webservice you could mark the password field/getter with [`@JsonIgnore`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.0.1/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnore.html) annotation, that way it wouldn't be included in the JSON returned by your controller.

If you are returning XML and your object is annotated with JAXB annotations, you can use [`@XmlTransient`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html) annotation to achieve the same result.

Comment: Is it a "standard" or a really common way to do ?

Comment: It is IMHO a standard way to exclude property from the object you want to serialize to JSON/XML. But if the object you are returning from your REST resource is more different from your model class then I guess more standard approach is to create a data transfer object (DTO) containing just the information you want to expose via your REST resource. In that case you would map your model object to this transfer object and return the transfer object from your controller. I like this solution because generally I don't want to pollute my model entities with Json annotations for instance.